# Проблема при работе с командной строкой

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, командная-строка

Я пытался написать вполне простого бота для Telegram(на Python), который, в ответ на определенную команду, будет присылать мне рандомные картинки из определенного API(в данном случае, это https://random.dog/)
ОДНАКО! При запуске бота через командую строку, для его дальнейшей работы уже в самом Телеграме, происходит следующее: сам файл так и не запускается, а командная строка попросту перестает реагировать(даже не выводит текст, который я ввожу с клавиатуры), хотя все еще продолжает работу

[image: Командная строка после выполнения файла]

Единственное, что в данном случае помогает, так это её перезапуск.

Я бы мог предположить, что проблема в самом коде (хотя это вполне возможно), но суть в том, что тоже самое происходит если я, скажем, возьму абсолютно любой похожий код бота, но уже из каких-нибудь других источников.
(Все таки странно, что из 3-4ёх кодов, не работает ни один из них и, судя по комментам, не работает ничего лишь у меня)

Заранее прошу простить, если вопрос глупый, просто раньше с таким никогда не сталкивался.

Сам код бота приведен ниже

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, InlineQueryHandler, CommandHandler
import requests
import re

def get_url(): # Функция для получения url 
    contents = requests.get('https://random.dog/woof.json').json()
    url = contents['url']
    return url

def dog(bot, update): # Функция отправки картинки
    url = get_url()
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=url)

def main():
    updater = Updater('Токен бота')
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('dog',dog))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что бот должен как-то реагировать на командную строку? Я могу и ошибаться, тк с телеграмм-ботами не работал, но, имхо, он и не должен. Через телеграмм вы пробовали ему команду отправить?

Comment: Как вы определяете, что «сам файл так и не запускается»? Бот не реагирует на сообщения в телеграме или что? Вообще, почему вы решили, что в командной строке должно что-то происходить, если в вашем коде нет ни единой строчки, взаимодействующей с командной строкой?

Comment: @andreymal 
Почему я думаю, что бот должен реагировать на командную строку? Ну, тут суть вот в чем...
Я запускаю самого бота через командую строку и проблема заключается в том, когда я вбиваю команду на запуск, то в ответ получаю вообще ничего. Хотя бы ошибку выдать мне явно должно, да и + ко всему, как я уже описывал выше, командная строка после этого вообще перестает как-то реагировать на ЛЮБЫЕ команды, но при этом работу продолжает...

Comment: @Александр Я уже пробовал отправить боту команды через телеграм, но это попросту ничего не давало. Так что, да, он никак не реагирует на мои сообщения.

Comment: Почему вы решили, что «Хотя бы ошибку» должно выдать? Что если ошибок нет, а причина нереагирования в чём-то другом? Если вы хотите что-то в командной строке, понаставьте print'ы в коде, например

Comment: @andreymal Решил сейчас проверить, выставив несколько принтов в коде. Как итог: сам текст принтов высвечивается, однако командная строка как не работала, так и не работает. Не, судя по работе принтов, значит явно проблема в коде, а не в cmd-шке. Это я теперь уже понял, но, в любом случае, проблема "не работы" кода все еще осталась

Comment: Попробуйте настроить logging как предлагается в документации, может с ним отпечатается что-нибудь интересное https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-Your-first-Bot

Comment: Также повесьте обработчик ошибок и в нём тоже печатайте ошибку, может тоже что-то интересное появится https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Exception-Handling

Comment: @Primper, а вы через российского оператора в интернет ходите? если да, то по решению роскомнадзора сервера телеграмма блокируются. родные телеграммские клиенты научились это преодолевать, но боты так не могут, т.к. ходят на api.telegram.com (если ничего не путаю), так что либо VPN, либо прокси вам помогут.

PS: код рабочий, картинки шлёт.

Comment: @kami Удивительно, но после включения VPN все заработало! Так что, можно считать, что проблема решена.
Благодарю

Comment: в общем-то это не удивительно, а вполне закономерно :) оформляю в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Primper, а вы через российского оператора в интернет ходите? если да, то по решению роскомнадзора сервера телеграмма блокируются. родные телеграммские клиенты научились это преодолевать, но боты так не могут, т.к. ходят на api.telegram.com (если правильно помню), так что либо VPN, либо прокси вам помогут.

PS: код рабочий, картинки шлёт.

Comment: Поставил плюсик в карму, теперь можете перенести в комментарий (хотя с другой стороны это слегка тянет на ответ, если и правда российский оператор)